# popup window on a drag and drop in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

How can I make a popup window appear when I drop an element in a box?
I have tried to use alert but I can't customize it to my liking. I've found someone else's code online to customize an alert but it isn't what I am looking for.

Should I use a bootstrap modal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ondrop`, or whatever drop event works best for you, just trigger a function like this (with sample arguments):

```
function myFunction() {
    window.open("urlOfPopup", "", "width=200,height=100");
}
```

Or without URL:

```
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("urlOfPopul", "", "width=200,height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>Popup content</p>");
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the simplest way to I was looking for... thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I have had great success with the following library:

https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/

Answer (score 0):

You can use different libraries to customise pop up experience. I would recommend you sweetalert and bootbox libraries. Bootbox is built upon Bootstrap modals with a lot of customisation. You can view the details on following links:

http://bootboxjs.com

Link on how to customise bootbox popup:
http://paynedigital.com/articles/2011/11/bootbox-js-alert-confirm-dialogs-for-twitter-bootstrap